# How to convert strings in a list to individual lists?

Tags: python, list

Consider, I have a list

```
subjects = ['subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3', 'subject4', 'subject5']
```

How do I convert these individual list elements to individual lists?

```
subject1 = [ ]
subject2 = [ ]
subject3 = [ ]
subject4 = [ ]
subject5 = [ ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a dictionnary ?

Comment: You probably want to use a dictionary, yeah. `subjects = {'subject1': [], 'subject2': [], ...}` and then use e.g. `subjects['subject1'].append(42)`. See the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
subjects = ['subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3', 'subject4', 'subject5']
ret = {}.fromkeys(subjects, [])
```

Then `ret` is

```
{'subject1': [], 'subject2': [], 'subject3': [], 'subject4': [], 'subject5': []}
```

-- EDIT --

As @Anand said, all the values are the same list reference. To avoid this, there's a workaround:

```
ret = {k: [] for k in subjects}
```

Comment: Please note in this scenario, all the values are the same list reference, so appending or mutating any of the lists, would reflect in all others.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thanks for reminding. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dictionnary, you can do the following :

```
dictionnary = dict((s, []) for s in subjects)
```

You can access your list by doing the following :

```
my_list = dictionnary['subject1']
my_list.append(5)
print(dictionnary['subject1'] == [5]) # True

# Or also
dictionnary['subject1'].append(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want induvidual lists, and not a dictionary:

```
for subject in subjects:
    exec(subject + " = list()")
```